# How To implement inner join on self dependent table

Tags: sql-server, database, join, self-join

`Categories`

```
1 | Pen       | 3
2 | Book      | 3
3 | Education | null
4 | Shirt     | null
```

`Product`

```
1 |  10.00 | Parker-Pen   | the description | 1000  | 1
2 |  35.00 | Dairy        | the description | 500   | 2
3 |  9.00  | Dux-Pen      | the description | 1000  | 1
4 | 350.00 | GeographyMap | the description | 30    | 3
4 | 250.00 | PoloShirt    | the description | 100   | 4
```

These are the tables which I was actually retrieving the product whose category id is 3.

Here is the query which i used to retrive the data

```
select p.name, c.name 
from product p 
    inner join Categories c on p.Categories_id=c.id 
    inner join Categories c2 on c2.id=3 or c2.parent=3
```

It is actually retrieving the data but in multiple time. And also have the poloshirt, which is not on the category id.

Can you explain me what is the problem and what is the better way for categorizing the product

Comment: Can you define what the data columns actually are? Also what is your expected output, because it is hard to understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: what is your expected output

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar i want to get the product whose category id is 3 and those also whose category id has parent id of 3

Comment: @dotnetom i want to get the product whose category id is 3 and those also whose category id has parent id of 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is only one level of hierarchy allowed, you should get an answer with such query:

```
select p.name, c.name 
from product p 
    inner join Categories c on p.Categories_id=c.id 
where c.id=3 or c.parent=3
```

Comment: You don't need second join, because you are not checking any conditions on the second table

Comment: how i can get multi level hierarchy with this table, does i have to change the table or i can obtain it through the sql command ?

Comment: You can add second level of hierarchy by for example setting parent of `Educarion` to `4`, but in this case the query that I wrote will not work

Comment: yah i know that this table is capable of the it, but i just want to know what will be the command